# Use VBA to set checkbox in table not form

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2013

In the code for a `SAVE` button, I want to save the record, and mark a checkbox in a specific table which is not the same table as the one where I am saving a record. It's basically like a checklist table to indicate something has been done. I know -1 represents a check mark so I have tried:

```
Me.tblProjectCompletion.Done = -1
```

and I have tried it without the `Me`.

I also tried putting it into a form first to save it into a table but that caused other problems. If I can save the check mark in the table I want for the projectID  it would be best, so I have also tried:

```
if ProjectCompletion.ProjectCompID = Project.ProjectID then tblProjectCompletion.Done = -1
```

But code like that is not working either.  Any suggestions?

```
Currentdb.Execute
Update ProjectCompletion
Set [ProjectCompletion].[Done] = -1
WHERE [ProjectCompletion].[ProjectCompID] = [Project].[ProjectID]
```

I've tried this code with and without brackets and quotes, and a semicolon at the end. With this pattern it stops on Execute and says `argument not optional`. The following code works. I just need to add the checking of the check box.

```
Private Sub Save_Record_Click()
DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdSaveRecord
If Me.Dirty Then
Me.Dirty = False
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: you need to use an update statement such as: CurrentDb.Execute "UPDATE TableName SET FieldName = -1 WHERE <Record to update condition>"

Comment: While it might be possible to bind a form to two tables at once using a query that joins the two and uses the DISTINCT keyword, you're probably better off using @Sorceri's suggestion to directly update that single field directly in the other table with SQL based on your criteria.

Comment: I like this approach a lot since I use Oracle, but I am getting a compile error saying end of statement expected. I tried it with the quote in front of UPDATE and without. Is there any syntax missing in what you gave me?  I really want it to work!

Comment: I would update your question with what you are using so we can see it.

Comment: I am using Access 2013... not MySQL. Is that what you mean?

Comment: no, I mean show us your update statement that is causing the error.  So after my suggestion what change did you make?

Comment: Sorry... just wanted to answer you properly. So I have updated it above. I tried it half a dozen ways. I would love for this way to work, because I am comfy with Oracle queries. I hope you can help me get it to work!

Comment: Are you changing 1 record  or all records in the ProjectCompletion table that have an ID in the Project table?

Comment: There is a save and a delete button for each record. I am able to save or delete the one record with a macro, so I know the buttons are acting on the one record they are supposed to act upon. Yes... only one record is saved or deleted at a time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, so I am guessing this is a form module.  The problem is that it has no clue what record you are looking to update so you need to use the CurrentRecord property

```
CurrentDb.Execute "UPDATE ProjectCompletion SET [ProjectCompletion].[Done] = -1 WHERE [ProjectCompletion].[ProjectCompID] = " & Me.Recordset.Fields("ProjectID").Value
```

Comment: You are right that it the save button is in a form (subform). I did it exactly the way you described. No compile error, but the box still has no check in it. I tried adding the right hand side of "=" back in front of Me.CurrentRecord just to try it, but again get a compile error. With the way you explained it, how does it know which field is the foreign key?

Comment: @985hunter CurrentRecord points to the current record # of the form, if these do not correspond to your record IDs then we need to get the record ID.   Can you show the macro for deleting and saving as this may help to determine how to obtain the correct Record ID.

Comment: I've added it in my question. I appreciate the help you are giving me!

Comment: @985hunter  I have updated the example to look at the recordset of the form and get the ProjectID

Comment: I really appreciate your patience! Your code is working!  Yay!  I have another problem now where I am not getting focus within another subform, so I need to work on that next. Thank you again for your help!

Comment: @985hunter  don't forget to mark the question as answered.